# How to change chart color with am4chart

Tags: javascript, reactjs, charts, colors, amcharts4

I'm using am4chart to making line chart on my website.
The background of the website is black, so I have to render the chart white
https://i.stack.imgur.com/eHMw9.jpg

I have try to change the chart fill when I create the chart, it absolutely dont work. But when I change chart stroke it work (but only the outline and this is ugly)

Here is the function where I create the chart

```
/* Creating chart and set language to french */
      let chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4charts.XYChart);
      chart.paddingRight = 20;      
      chart.language.locale = am4lang_fr_FR;
      chart.fill = am4core.color("#fff")
      //chart.stroke = am4core.color("#fff")

      /* Create date, values axis and cursor */
      let dateAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.DateAxis());  
      dateAxis.renderer.grid.template.location = 0;
      let valueAxis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());
      valueAxis.tooltip.disabled = true;
      valueAxis.renderer.minWidth = 35;      
      chart.cursor = new am4charts.XYCursor();

      /* Setting up the scrollbar */
      let scrollbarX = new am4charts.XYChartScrollbar();      
      chart.scrollbarX = scrollbarX;
```

I want the date and value axis and the scollbar writting to be blank (link in my image but without stroke)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/24xQM.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to access `background` property of a chart. `chart` itself has no `fill` property. Use it like this:

```
chart.background.fill = am4core.color("#123")
```

---

**UPDATE:**
To change the color of the axis labels you need to do that manually on `AxisLabel` object. In your case I think it should look something like this:

```
dateAxis.renderer.labels.template.fill = am4core.color("#fff");
valueAxis.renderer.labels.template.fill = am4core.color("#fff");
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for answer

But its not what im looking for.

Your solution turn the background of my entire chart into a color. I want only the text in white

Comment: @Dima Mamchur this is exactly what i was looking for